# Saving multiple rows in a single query

Tags: cakephp

Is there anyway to have cake do a multi-row insert in a single query without writing raw SQL to do this? The saveMany and saveAssociated options will only save multiple rows in a single transaction, but that transaction contains multiple insert statements so these methods are clearly not a solution to write heavy applications.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone pointed me towards the Big Data Behavior https://github.com/jmillerdesign/CakePHP_Big_Data

Comment: Careful =). That behavior has a (possibly) handy API, but IS writing raw sql. If your data isn't simple you're going to get sql syntax errors - it only does basic [value quoting](https://github.com/jmillerdesign/CakePHP_Big_Data/blob/master/Model/Behavior/BigDataBehavior.php#L146). Also looks like it doesn't let you do anything except full row insert/updates. If you want to use it anyway I suggest updating to simply call [insertMulti](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L2894), unescaped raw sql queries are a problem waiting to happen.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

Though it's not a common practice to do so in app-land code, and doing so removes the possibility to use almost any application logic (validation rules, behaviors, events etc.). You can see an example of doing this in the way [fixtures are loaded](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/TestSuite/Fixture/CakeTestFixture.php#L284):

```
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');

$table = "stuffs";
$fields = array('id', 'name');
$values = array(
    array(1, 'one'),
    array(2, 'two'),
    ...
);

$result = $db->insertMulti($table, $fields, $values);
```

You may also find [this repository](https://github.com/lorenzo/cakephp-fixturize) useful (either directly or as a basis for your code) which loads fixture files into your app database - using multi-inserts.

Comment: it appears this still inserts a single row at a time wrapped up in a single transaction...

Comment: Hah! [Didn't notice that](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L2917). If you're doing this often enough for it to make the difference, as noted in the comment for the big-data-behavior-answer, make sure your chosen solution is escaping values appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Big_Data is good idea for inserting bulk. But as AD7six note, it still use basic value quoting and does not return insert ids. And base on your ideas, i wrote small script to inserting bulk in a single query, using default CakePHP quoting and returning ids of inserted records.

```
    $count = count($records);
    $dbSource = $this->getDataSource();
    $table = $dbSource->fullTableName($this->table);
    $fields = $dbSource->prepareFields($this, array('fields' => array_keys($records[0])));
    $values = array();
    foreach ($records as $index => $record) {
        if (!is_array($record) || !$record) {
            return null;
        }
        foreach ($record as $column => $value) {
            $values[$index][$column] = $dbSource->value($value, $this->getColumnType($column));
        }
        $values[$index] = '(' . implode(',', $values[$index]) . ')';
    }

    $query = 'INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES %s;';

    $query = sprintf($query, $table, implode(',', $fields), implode(',', $values));
    if (!$dbSource->execute($query)) {
        return false;
    }
    $lastInsertId = $dbSource->getConnection()->lastInsertId();
    $insertIds = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $insertIds[] = $lastInsertId + $i;
    }
    return $insertIds;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CakePHP 3.0 you can check the answer to this question: [How to use insert in query builder insert multiple records?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26592779/1447468)

If you are using CakePHP 2 you will have to use **raw SQL** like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `people` (`name`,`title`) VALUES ";
foreach($people as $person){
    list($name,$title) = $person;
    $sql.= "('$name','$title'),";
}
$this->query(substr($sql,0,-1));
```

Source: [Inserting Multiple Rows with CakePHP 3](http://blog.cnizz.com/2014/10/29/inserting-multiple-rows-with-cakephp-3/)

Answer (score -1):

yes you can use like below

The `getDataSource()` method is static in CakePHP 2.x, so you should be able to use:

```
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
$db->rawQuery($some_sql);
```

here i am posting method to do. you have to create some `SQL` statement manually to insert multiple row in one time.

Please let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: I know how to do this with traditional SQL, I want to stay within my framework. Raw SQL is last resort. I found this: https://github.com/jmillerdesign/CakePHP_Big_Data