# How to use insert in query builder insert multiple records?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying the following in CakePHP 3:

```
   $newUsers = [
        [
            'username' => 'Felicia',
            'age' => 27,
        ],
        [
            'username' => 'Timmy',
            'age' => 71,
        ],
    ];

    $insertQuery = $this->Users->query();

    $insertQuery->insert(array_keys($newUsers[0]))
                ->values($newUsers)
                ->execute();
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

SQL Query: INSERT INTO users (username, age) VALUES (:c0, :c1, :c2, :c3)
```

I was expecting `INSERT INTO users (username, age) VALUES (:c0, :c1), (:c2, :c3);` as the query.

I turned on the log for the database config and I see:

```
2014-10-27 16:10:26 Debug: INSERT INTO users (username, age) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'Array', 'Array')
```

Please help me understand if I misunderstood the potential of using query builder in CakePHP 3.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tested. This works.

```
   $newUsers = [
        [
            'username' => 'Felicia',
            'age' => 27,
        ],
        [
            'username' => 'Timmy',
            'age' => 71,
        ],
    ];

    $columns = array_keys($newUsers[0]);
```

Alert! There are two ways to do mass insert. This is one way:

```
    $insertQuery = $this->Users->query();

    $newUsersValuesExpression = new ValuesExpression($columns, $insertQuery->typeMap()->types([]));
    $newUsersValuesExpression->values($newUsers);

    $insertQuery->insert($columns)
                ->values($newUsersValuesExpression)
                ->execute();
```

As suggested by ndm, I prefer this way.

```
    $insertQuery = $this->Users->query();

    $insertQuery->insert($columns);

    // you must always alter the values clause AFTER insert
    $insertQuery->clause('values')->values($newUsers);

    $insertQuery->execute();
```

Comment: Your second method has worked for me in Cakephp 3.0

Comment: @kim - how I can get the all inserted data after query execution?
Like this insertion method returning the inserted data $this->saveMany($this->newEntities($inser_data));

Answer (score 3):

You can either combine multiple `value()` calls:

```
// ...

foreach($newUsers as $values)
{
    $query->values($values);
}
$query->execute();
```

or modify the `ValuesExpression` object directly (accessible via [**`Query::clause()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_clause)), which has a `values()` method that allows to set all data at once:

```
// ...

$query->clause('values')->values($newUsers);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: I think you did not phrase it exactly correct, but thank you! You did point to me another way to derive the ValuesExpression

Comment: @KimStacks What do you think was phrased wrong? The missing fact that values need to be applied after invoking `insert()`? That's generally how it has to be done. Also note that it's not necessary to reapply the `ValuesExpression` instance.

Comment: Oops sorry you were right. I will change my answer. Man, you are good. How long you have been using Cake3?

Comment: By the way, do you have a blog or something that I can follow? I like to learn from good developers like yourself

Comment: @KimStacks I'm not really using (as in using it in an actual project) CakePHP 3 yet, I'm justing testing specific things here and there, however I've been following the development since it's beginning, I'm watching all the issues and pull requests on GitHub, ocassionally contributing code and fixes, and last but not least I'm trying to solve problems by people here on SO (when I should actually be working of course), that's my way of becoming acquainted with code. And no, I don't have a blog, my public activity is limited to SO and [**GitHub**](https://github.com/ndm2).

Comment: Thank you. Followed u on GitHub. Look forward meeting you in person or over #cakephp irc channel

Comment: I am going to give you 100 points because your answer was very helpful to me. Apparently I needed to wait 23 hrs to award after starting the bounty.

Comment: @KimStacks Well, thanks, I won't reject them, but please don't feel obligated to this just because you haven't accepted _my_ answer or similar :)

Comment: @ndm How would you do that with Cake 2.X ? [EDIT] Just found this: http://blog.cnizz.com/2014/10/29/inserting-multiple-rows-with-cakephp-3/

Comment: @Techbrunch **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035559/saving-multiple-rows-in-a-single-query**